# PyInstaller Edit existing --onefile executable to disable console

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have a Python program that was built and distributed as one Windows executable file.

It was probably packaged with the option `--onefile` enabled by PyInstaller. I read the project documentation and they left the `--noconsole` OFF (so it has a console) for developers. This bothers me terribly for some reason so I would like to edit/change the executable to disable the console window.

Although I have the skills to rebuild it and package it myself from sources, I really don't want to go through the hassle so I was wondering if anybody knows how I can either disable the console entirely or just hide it permanently.

Thanks.

Comment: You work this one out?  Same issue here.  Spammed with error messages with console.  I think I have better luck tackling error messages then disable console

Comment: @TheGman I never did, and old questions on StackOverflow rarely ever see answers unless deleted and re-asked.